# Set value of select to first child of that select

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code dynamically generates the options for the select element but the exact value of the options are unknown at the moment of creation.
So was playing around to set the selected value of my select element to the first child but was unable to do so in 1 line.
I was able to it in 2 lines but I was wondering if something shorter is possible.

```
<select id="selectElement">
   <option value="1">Optie 1</option>
   <option value="2">Optie 2</option>
</select>

$("#selectElement").val($(this).children(":first").val());
```

Comment: use `$("#selectElement option:first")`

Comment: `$("#selectElement option:nth-child(1)")` or `$("#selectElement option").eq(o)`

Comment: It's worth noting that most browsers will automatically select that first option for you.

Comment: ugh, of course, I was so focussed on "this" that I looked past the most obvious. TGIF

Comment: `$("#selectElement option:first-child").prop('selected', true)`

Answer (score 2):

It's worth noting that most browsers will automatically select that first option for you.

But if you need to do it for some reason: You're not far off at all, but `this` doesn't come from the first part of that line. Instead:

```
var select = $("#selectElement");
select.val(select.children(":first").val());
```

Or I find this simpler:

```
var select = $("#selectElement");
select.val(select[0].options[0].value);
```

Or using the `selected` property of the option instead:

```
$("#selectElement")[0].options[0].selected = true;
// or with more jQuery
$("#selectElement > option:first").prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: hi just want to as why you need to select `[0]` from `$("#selectElement")` i am assuming that it is only since it is id why need select first from that?

Comment: @guradio: If `select` refers to a jQuery object (as it does above), `select[0]` gets the first DOM element that the jQuery object wraps. Since I wanted to access the `options` property on the actual `HTMLSelectElement` instance, I used `select[0]` to do that. (Then `options[0]` because I wanted the first entry in the options collection.)

Answer (score 1):

One method is using `.eq()` selector.It reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

Please try this:

```
$(selectElement).val($('#selectElement option:eq(0)').val());
```

See reference [here](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

If you want the shortest method please try this:

```
$("#selectElement").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one element, you should find it (with # id selector), and the also use his selector to find the children.

Otherwise you could use (in case you also have more elements) use a class, and iterate it (the second script in the snippet)

**edit**

Without js, you could simply use the `selected` property of option to set as default when page loads.

```js
$("#selectElement").val($("#selectElement").children("option:first").val());

$(".selectElement").each(function() {
  $(this).val($(this).children("option:first").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectElement">
  <option value="1">Optie 1</option>
  <option value="2">Optie 2</option>
</select>


<select class="selectElement">
  <option value="21">Optie 21</option>
  <option value="22">Optie 22</option>
</select>


<select>
  <option selected value="321">Optie 321</option>
  <option value="322">Optie 322</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `:first`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
         $("#selectElement").val($("#selectElement option:first").val())
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectElement">
   <option value="1">Optie 1</option>
   <option value="2">Optie 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use JavaScript to set selected the first element of the `option`s because html will do it for you:

```html
<select id="selectElement">
  <option value="1">Optie 1</option>
  <option value="2">Optie 2</option>
</select>
```